# How to complete a Task from another function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to query data from a database via a webservice. The provided API allows to send batch requests, so that multiple requests are sent in a single HTTP request. I'd like to make benefit from this and am trying to build a C# interface to use this service using async code and Tasks.

My goal is to achieve something like the following:

```
// Service class that abstracts the server interface.
class Service
{
    // Return all StateA objects at the next server contact.
    public Task<IEnumerable<StateA>> GetStatesA() { ... }
    // Return all StateB objects at the next server contact.
    public Task<IEnumerable<StateB>> GetStatesB() { ... }
    // Send all queued requests to the server.
    public Task SendRequests() { ... }
}
```

Usage of the API:

```
// Query all StateA and StateB objects from the database and
// process them as soon as they arrive.
service.GetStatesA().ContinueWith((t) => DoSomething(t.Result));
service.GetStatesB().ContinueWith((t) => DoSomething(t.Result));

// Some other code

// Actually access the API such that the data is queried and the Tasks completed.
service.SendRequests();
```

From my knowledge, Tasks in C# can only wrap synchronous functions and return when they finish. Is there any way to complete a Task from the outside?

I'm looking for something similar to e.g. the Completer class in Dart (see https://api.dartlang.org/1.13.0/dart-async/Completer-class.html).

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to not return Task<IEnumerable<T>>.  Instead return a materialized list...  Personally I have experienced unexpected results when trying to combine both the deferred execution of an iterator and the async/await state machine.

http://ctigeek.net/using-asyncawait-with-ienumerable-and-yield-return/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    public Task GetStateA()
    {
        // Do stuff;
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task GetStateB()
    {
        //Do stuff
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public async Task QueryApiAsync()
    {
        // Query the API
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Although possible to use, it looks to me like the API you're exposing isn't really convenient. I wouldn't want `GetStateA()` to return a `Task` which only completes once the batch query executes. I would rather have a some sort of batch method which is provided with an `IEnumerable<States>` and returns to the caller once the batch completes. If you're not really planning on allowing a single state to query the API.

So, I would either turn the API methods that has an `Enqueue` method which invokes a callback:

```
public interface Foo
{
    void Enqueue<T>(T state, Action callback) where T : State;
}
```

Or actually expose the functionality of making a singular call to the API, as well as a Batch operation:

```
public interface Foo
{
    Task<List<StateA>> GetStatesAAsync();
    Task<List<StateB>> GetStatesBAsync();
    Task<List<IState>> GetBatchStatesAsync(IEnumerable<IState> states);
}
```

Comment: TaskCompletionSource is really powerful - I personally use it when integration-testing my SignalR event emissions. E.g. `var evt = await testContext.ExpectEvent<SomeEvent>()`, makes the test very readable.

Comment: @Jeff Definitely. Though in this particular situation, I'm not sure that's what the OP should really be using.

Comment: While I agree that this isn't the primary use-case for TCS, it *does* make things pretty easy to implement.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't completely understand what the  `GetBatchStatesAsync(IEnumerable<IState> states)` should do. Why should I provide an enumerable here? How does it determine which kind of state it should request from the server?

Comment: @user3486395 It was just an example. I'm not really sure which parameter need to be passed to your batch method. But generally, does the batch operation care about the kind of state it needs? Or do you simply have to serialize the request to the service? There are many things that can be done, I just tried to create an example of a better asynchronous API I would of wanted.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Ah ok. They type of the state is important because it describes service method that should be called at the server. It is also possible to filter the states e.g. based on a time range.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to not return Task<IEnumerable<T>>.  Instead return a materialized list...  Personally I have experienced unexpected results when trying to combine both the deferred execution of an iterator and the async/await state machine.

http://ctigeek.net/using-asyncawait-with-ienumerable-and-yield-return/

Comment: @DavidPine You're right. Async and lazily deferred execution don't work well together, yet. Perhaps in C#-7 we'll get to see `IAsyncEnumerable` baked into the type system.

Answer (score 0):

> Tasks in C# can only wrap synchronous functions and return when they finish. Is there any way to complete a Task from the outside?

I wanted to take a stab at answering this part of the question (agreeing with @Yuval Itzchakov). The `Task` and `Task<T>` classes were introduced in the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx), with .NET 4.0. Initially the desired means on using the task classes was with the fluent API, i.e.; chaining `ContinueWith`.  Today, however; it is preferred to use the async / await keywords with Task returning methods.  Using await will "complete" the task from the outside, assuming that is what you meant.  The [await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) keyword will suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.

Comment: My main idea is that I batch different actions (query data but also push new data) into a single server access. I chose to use `ContinueWith` because I don't want my thread to be blocked everytime I queue some work but only once if I call `await SendRequests()`. When the response of the server arrived, I want all previously queued work to be executed automatically.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes more sense now...  I would consider using a ConcurrentQueue<T> then, as it is thread safe and you could enqueue what you need and then send requests by way of dequeuing and sending.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx